# Default value in XSLT dropdown list

Tags: c#, xslt

I'm trying to set a preselected value in a XSLT drop down list. So that if outcome answer is populated

This works, but I only have outcome answer set on one of the prompts, and it then sets it for any other subsequent drop down list that also contains the answered outcome.

```
 <xsl:if test="count(PromptOutcomes/PromptOutcome/Outcome) > 3">
        <div class="promptText">
          <select class="promptOutcomes" name="PromptOutcomes" tag="{ID}" id="PromptResponse">
            <xsl:for-each select="PromptOutcomes/PromptOutcome">
              <xsl:variable name="outcomeAnswer" select="//AnsweredOutcome"></xsl:variable>                  
              <option value="{Outcome}" tag="PromptResponse">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="Outcome = $outcomeAnswer">
                    <xsl:attribute name="selected">
                      selected
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>                    
                <xsl:value-of select="Outcome"/>
              </option>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </select>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>     
    </div>
```

Xml

```
<Prompt>
        <DateOfAnswer>2014-09-05T15:08:00</DateOfAnswer>
        <ID>226</ID>
        <SelectedOutcome/>
        <AnsweredOutcome>Lead Generated passed to SLD</AnsweredOutcome>
        <PromptOutcomes>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome/>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>No</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Not Interested</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Interested but no follow up</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Lead Generated passed to SLD</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Interested referred to IFA</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Customer Unhappy do not ask again</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
        </PromptOutcomes>
        <PromptMessage>Does the customer have pensions elsewhere they'd like to consolidate with Standard Life?</PromptMessage>
        <ChildMessages/>
        <PromptType>Opportunity</PromptType>
        <Link>ConsolidationGuide</Link>
        <Priority>22</Priority>
    </Prompt>
    <Prompt>
        <DateOfAnswer xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ID>227</ID>
        <SelectedOutcome/>
        <PromptOutcomes>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome/>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>In new employers scheme</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Left Employer</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Restart customer/employer contributions</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>No restart of customer/employer contributions</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Customer Unhappy do not ask again</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Plan Updated to Direct</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Not Interested</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>No other pensions</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Interested but no follow up</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Lead Generated passed to SLD</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
            <PromptOutcome>
                <Outcome>Interested referred to IFA</Outcome>
            </PromptOutcome>
        </PromptOutcomes>
        <PromptMessage>Possible workplace leaver</PromptMessage>
        <ChildMessages>
            <PromptMessage>
                <Message>Does the customer have any other pensions?</Message>
            </PromptMessage>
            <PromptMessage>
                <Message>Has customer left employer?</Message>
            </PromptMessage>
            <PromptMessage>
                <Message>Restart customer/employer payments?</Message>
            </PromptMessage>
        </ChildMessages>
        <PromptType>Opportunity</PromptType>
        <Priority>23</Priority>
    </Prompt>
```

So the drop down list for the 2nd prompt is selected even although it doesn't have an Answered outcome. I've tried adding an otherwise, and setting the attribute of selected to something else but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
<xsl:variable name="outcomeAnswer" select="//AnsweredOutcome"></xsl:variable>
```

This selects all AnsweredOutcome elements, and the first one gets used in the equality. Try this instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="outcomeAnswer" select="../../AnsweredOutcome"></xsl:variable>
```

Or better yet skip the variable and change your xsl:test to:

```
<xsl:when test="Outcome = ../../AnsweredOutcome">
```